# Monitoring clipboard

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am writting dll with global hooks. One of the task is viewing clipboard and deleting all data from it when someone perform copy operation. Here is my callback function for window:

```
string test("my data");

LRESULT CALLBACK WndHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            nextClipboardViewer = SetClipboardViewer(windowHandler);
            MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;
        case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
            if((HWND) wParam == nextClipboardViewer) 
                nextClipboardViewer == (HWND) lParam;
            else if(nextClipboardViewer != NULL)
                SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, msg, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
            if(OpenClipboard(windowHandler)) {
                EmptyClipboard();
                HGLOBAL hClipboardData;
                hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, test.size() + 1);
                char * pchData;
                pchData = (char*)GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
                memcpy(pchData, test.c_str(), test.size() + 1);
                GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
                SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hClipboardData);
                CloseClipboard();
            }
            SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, msg, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            ChangeClipboardChain(windowHandler, nextClipboardViewer);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am just trying replace information in clipboard, but this code doesn't work.

**Updated:** Now i am using invisible window and SetClipboardViewer for monitoring changes. But data in clipboard doesn't change.

Comment: Even if this could be made to work, all you would trap is instances where the `WM_COPY` message is used to place data on the clipboard - there's no guarantee it will be. Creating a window and using `SetClipboardViewer` or `AddClipboardFormatListener` is a much better solution.

Comment: There's no point in emptying the clipboard *before* the app copies data to it.  Wrong hook, use WH_CALLWNDPROCRET.  And you really *do* want to use SetClipboardViewer.  If you don't have a HWND then just create one, it doesn't have to be visible.  Make sure your uninstaller is flawless as well, it will get a good workout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it's really safe to change the contents of the clipboard while processing a `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` message - at the very least I'm surprised you don't trigger an infinite loop (since your calls to `EmptyClipboard()` and `SetClipboardData()` could be triggering another `WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD` message). Possibly the system has protection against that - I've never tried to find out - but it still feels wrong :)

Try this version, which:

1. Moves the clipboard update to a separate message that the window posts to itself (moving it outside of the clipboard change the notification code)
2. Uses a global flag to ignore changes it makes itself.

Note: I think the actual bug with your code was that when you're processing `WM_CREATE`,  `windowHandler` is not yet assigned. You are presumably setting that to the value `CreateWindowEx` returns, but when `WM_CREATE` is being processed `CreateWindowEx` hasn't actually returned yet. This means the clipboard viewer is never actually established correctly. I've changed the references to use `hwnd` to fix this.

```cpp
string test("my data");

#define MSG_UPDATECLIPBOARD     (WM_APP + 1)
static bool g_fIgnoreClipboardChange = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndHandler(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        nextClipboardViewer = SetClipboardViewer(hwnd);
        MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;
    case WM_CHANGECBCHAIN:
        if((HWND) wParam == nextClipboardViewer) 
            nextClipboardViewer = (HWND) lParam;
        else if(nextClipboardViewer != NULL)
            SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    case WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD:
        if (!g_fIgnoreClipboardChange)
            PostMessage(hwnd, MSG_UPDATECLIPBOARD, 0, 0);
        if(nextClipboardViewer != NULL)
            SendMessage(nextClipboardViewer, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    case MSG_UPDATECLIPBOARD:
        g_fIgnoreClipboardChange = true;
        if(OpenClipboard(hwnd)) {
            HGLOBAL hClipboardData;
            hClipboardData = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, test.size() + 1);
            char * pchData;
            pchData = (char*)GlobalLock(hClipboardData);
            memcpy(pchData, test.c_str(), test.size() + 1);
            GlobalUnlock(hClipboardData);
            SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hClipboardData);
            CloseClipboard();
        }
        g_fIgnoreClipboardChange = false;
        break;      
    case WM_DESTROY:
        ChangeClipboardChain(hwnd, nextClipboardViewer);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. My head pain was wrong window handler in SetClipboardViewer() function. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: I am just learning C++ and have a very simple question for you: I am trying to use this code to create a new thread in my console win32 application. I am getting an error on "nextClipboardViewer" is undefined. What library do I include to solve this problem? I googled it but found nothing on this specific function and library imports; I'm assuming that's my issue.

Comment: That code came from the OP and was just a fragment, it wasn't a full program. If you add `HWND nextClipboardViewer = 0;` **outside** a function (to make it a global) it should get you past that error, but I'm not sure what other errors you'll encounter using just a fragment of someone else's code.

Comment: Thank you. I find it hard to tell in C++ when there's an error because of a missing library or something completely different. (VS 2015)